# Understanding js return type

Tags: javascript

I have a function called which is returning ref to object literal `nameObj`. I want to access methods in the returned object but I am getting js error. why is `setNameObj` method not available on `nameObj` object?

```
       var nameObj=function(){

            var _locname;

            return {
                item:'item1',
                getNameObj: function(){
                    return _locname
                },
                setNameObj: function(nm){
                    _locname = nm
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(nameObj.setNameObj('tempValue'));
        console.log(nameObj.getNameObj());
```

Comment: Because `nameObj` is a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're setting `nameObj` to be the function and not the result of that function. It looks like you want an IIFE here, so just add parentheses at the end of your function expression:

```js
      var nameObj=function(){

            var _locname;

            return {
                item:'item1',
                getNameObj: function(){
                    return _locname
                },
                setNameObj: function(nm){
                    _locname = nm
                }
            }
        }();
        console.log(nameObj.setNameObj('tempValue'));
        console.log(nameObj.getNameObj());
```

Comment: Thats what I wanted to do, forgot to make it IIFE :-)

Answer (score 6):

Because `nameObj` is a function *that returns an object that will have your methods!*

Try calling it *and then* calling functions on the result:

```
console.log(nameObj().setNameObj('tempValue'));
console.log(nameObj().getNameObj());
```

Of course in this case it's largely moot, because each call will create a new closure. You most probably want one variable (or just convert `nameObj` to an IIFE).

```
var obj = nameObj();
obj.setNameObj('tempValue');
console.log(obj.getNameObj());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: don't expect firs log to log anything actualy. As setNameObj has no return value, it will log undefined.

Comment: @100r Good one. I've edited my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Since nameObj is a function, you have to put the brackets after them to evaluate:
nameObj()

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is this:

```
var nameObj= (function(){

        var _locname;

        return {
            item:'item1',
            getNameObj: function(){
                return _locname
            },
            setNameObj: function(nm){
                _locname = nm
            }
        }
    })();
    console.log(nameObj.setNameObj('tempValue'));
    console.log(nameObj.getNameObj());
```

Note the added parentheses (two sets) around the nameObj definition. There's a notable difference between getting a function, and getting the result of a function.